# Adding a border to floating element causes the last div to wrap

Tags: html, css

I have the following html/css. When I leave the borders off, everything lines up correctly, but if I put the borders on the center div then the right side's content shows up under everything else. How can I fix this?

```css
#container {} #left {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
#center {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid black; /*this causes the 'right' div to wrap*/
  border-right: 1px solid black; /*this causes the 'right' div to wrap*/
}
#right {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">I am left</div>
  <div id="center">I am center</div>
  <div id="right">I am right</div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `box-sizing: border-box` so that the width of border is included in width of elements, otherwise its `60% + 1px + 1px` + `2 * 20%` and that is more then `100%`.

```css
#container > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#left {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
#center {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#right {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">I am left</div>
  <div id="center">I am center</div>
  <div id="right">I am right</div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Note: `box-sizing: border-box` will also include `padding`   but not the margins.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS's `calc()` function. As you've assigned `width: 60%` to the `#center` when you're applying borders it is increasing the width by **2px**, to compensate that:

```
#center {
  width: calc(60% - 2px);
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
#container{}
#left{
  width:20%;
  float: left;
}
#center {
  width: calc(60% - 2px);
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid black; /* this causes the 'right' div to wrap */
  border-right: 1px solid black; /* this causes the 'right' div to wrap */
}
#right {
   float: left;
   width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">I am left</div>
  <div id="center">I am center</div>
  <div id="right">I am right</div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!